# obtain the ";" in liquibase output sql when using mssql

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

Is there any way to control the output of the Liquibase command `updateSql` when running on Microsoft SQL Server, so that the resulting SQL text is terminated with the `;` instead of the `GO`, similarly to what is done by default for PostgreSQL?

**Current output for SQL Server:**

```
CREATE TABLE T0000 ([field1] varchar(255), field2 varchar(255))
GO
    
ALTER TABLE T0000 ALTER COLUMN [field1] varchar(255) NOT NULL
GO
```

**Output for PostgreSQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE public."T0000" (field1 TEXT, field2 TEXT);
    
ALTER TABLE public."T0000" ALTER COLUMN  field1 SET NOT NULL;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had some result doing:

`cat original-sql-file.sql | sed -z 's/\nGO\n/;\n/g'`

but this  is done as Liquibase output post-processing.

I would like to know if  it is possible to obtain this "natively" with some Liquibase setting/command or whatever.